# Error creating OpenShift application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, openshift

I am attempting to create/deploy an application onto the Redhat OpenShift Express platform, and am attempting to do this via eclipse using the JBoss OpenShift plugins.

I am following the instructions here: https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/blogs/getting-started-with-the-openshift-eclipse-plug-in-for-java-applications-on-the-cloud

But when entering my user credentials I get an error preventing me getting any further:

```
 Could not check user credentials: Could not unmarshall response "




    {"data":
        {"user_info":
            {"env_vars":null,
            "max_gears":5,
            "system_ssh_keys":null,
            "uuid":"5a81de3405fe4ac6b5718dbb8540736f",
            "rhc_domain":"rhcloud.com",
            "rhlogin":"robert.hinds@accenture.com",
            "ssh_keys":
                {"laptop":{"type":"ssh-rsa","key":"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAw5GIjtI+B42SBv2kmV32OHI5tCBO7JWmlhF7w9dNy2Tp7MNtK8nE7nLUKYyXSZRzK0i4azPuMDDmmJ4jFpcyAwRdzBM43xZLo/6MlMFneT3t66ukNMNOgYptiRH7Zy8Tmjquwu2dXpui77tRQaEpq4Ms/JxHvanD+YMDNTXlrv8gIDwOjhtetuyeKbf/sr+UK1Bit8eDTgai01UmjXm+u/0Hi1tD6oG/GwNviQKb/2gmrmEs0uPhcJ9Olzrn67Gyu7c2PFOjTEvOXMQHjSUrVp905t8SzffiJ7uWzVnvufrweC5gXlR/v1tp3FrFgRcZVmZX6QlhyOiy5Tr1cLD8pw=="}},
                "consumed_gears":0,
                "vip":false,
                "namespace":"star",
                "ssh_key":null,
                "ssh_type":null
                },
            "app_info":{}
        },
        "api_c":["placeholder"],
        "messages":"",
        "broker_c":["namespace","rhlogin","ssh","app_uuid","debug","alter","cartridge","cart_type","action","app_name","api"],
        "exit_code":0,
        "debug":"",
        "api":"1.1.3",
        "result":""
    }
```

has anyone come across this previously? I am on Win7 Eclipse Indigo on JDK7

---

Update:

I get this problem using the following versions/steps

1. Using Eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857
2. Installed the OpenShift express tools from the JBoss software update site here: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ today (the current version that is downloaded today!)
3. Then simply file > new > openshift aplication, then enter my username and password (created today with OpenShift Express) and I get the error.

hope thats helpful - will wait for the update to the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a "known" issue in the sense that you're not the first that reported this:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-11431

The "interesting" part is that unmarshalling the response fails because of the following 2 properties with null values:

```
"ssh_key":null,
"ssh_type":null
```

This error occurrs since OpenShift added support for several keys. We fixed the unmarhslling issue but still dont know how to reproduce it. If you can we'd be very happy to get your instructions.

The fixed version of our client plugin will make it to our nightly update site in a few days. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks! updated my original question with further details. Will await the update, will it be before the end of next week do you think?

Comment: The version that is currently in our nightly update site does not have that problem any more:    
    
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-11445  
    
Unfortunately the fix is not complete yet in the sense that it seems not to handle timeouts in a smooth manner yet (you get an general error that does not specify what went wrong). But it should definitely solve your problem.    
    
You may install it from our nightly update site at:  
  
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/nightly/core/trunk/  
  
Please report back if things dont work for you.